# Mysql5.5 migration to RDS/Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

We have an mysql 5.5 installed and running on an AWS ec2 instance (r3.4xlarge type). We want to migrate to RDS/Aurora

1- RDS/Aurora can support mysql 5.6 and above. Should we first upgrade our database then move it to RDS/Aurora? Or can we do that using mysqldump directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurora has the ability to import from a 5.5 backup created with Percona XtraBackup.  Dump the 5.5 database, put the backup in S3, and create aurora from that backup.

You may be able to set up replication from your ec2 instance to RDS MySQL or Aurora, as long as you're not using MyISAM tables.

Finally, you can use the AWS Database Migration tool to migrate from MySQL to Aurora.

Comment: No, you can't use the AWS Database Migration. Could you please suggest an instruction on replication set up between 5.5 and aurora, otherwise that is not really helpful.

Comment: @Ilya:  MySQL 5.5 is a supported data source, as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html (As of Aug. 2019 at least)

Comment: I'm just outlining it here. I'm fighting with migrating Mysql 5.5 to Aurora Serverless. And it seems that there is no way to do it atm.

Comment: Migrate to RDS Aurora, then go to serverless.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to do it? I might be missing something, but looks like that is not possible. I was able to migrate db manually using mysql client and mysqldump command. Looks like it's the only way for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, one is use database migration services to migrate the database from MySQL 5.5 to Aurora DB, it is recommended migration tool by Amazon, using this method you can be migrated without any outage.

Second is take backup and directly import in Aurora, it will be fast if both instances are in same region else move back up to s3 and restore it.